# Android, get Resource?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I'm creating an air extension using android, I'm having trouble with the android part.

I get mySound using context.getResourceId, what var type should mySound be?

```
public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
    mySound = (context.getResourceId("my_sound"));
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html look under "Using MediaPlayer"

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since you've asked your question but just in case here is my answer :
the method `context.getResourceId` from `FREContext` class is a substitute to the usual R.xxx.my_resource_name in Android. So it will return a `int` that you can use in regular android method like `findResourceById` from `View` class for example. Basically you HAVE to use it everywhere a resource identifier is expected when using Air Native Extension. Here is a full example :

```
// When using ANE with the FREContext class
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(asContext.getResourceId("id.authButton"));

// Regular Android way where R is your resource file containing all the resource identifier
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton));
```